Question about sentence structure
I'd like you to check if my reading is correct. Please read the sentence below.

No matter how well you can drive, we learned, you have to be ready for children to run out into the street, animals to appear in your path, and other drivers to do dangerous things without warning.

I think "without warning" means "suddenly" and modifies "to run out", "to appear" and "to do". Am I right? Is it unlikely that "without warning" modifies only "to do"?

I think it more naturally modifies "do dangerous things". It's subjective though - "do dangerous things without warning" naturally feels like a unit. (I'm sure there are similar questions but can't think how to search for them.)

Thank you for answering my question! Another person has a different opinion. It's difficult to decide...

It's possible to write ambiguous sentences in English. Either interpretation can be correct.

Although all three activities could happen without warning, children and animals will always act without warning. To have it apply it to all three, I'd add "to do dangerous things, all without warning."

Does this answer your question? There is a soldier on the hill whom he sees with binoculars // The correct ways to disambiguate here are:  'No matter how well you can drive, we learned, you have to be ready for  other drivers to do dangerous things without warning, for children to run out into the street, and for  animals to appear in your path.' / 'No matter how well you can drive, we learned, you have to be ready for children to  ...

run out into the street, for animals to appear in your path, and for other drivers to do dangerous things – all  without warning.'
